# How to turn off triggers for a specific period?

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-agent

I have an action which ping the zabbix agents of my servers and a trigger which notifies if there are more than 3 minutes without answer. The expression is:

```
{template_zabbix_agent:agent.ping.nodata(3m)}=1
```

It was working well, but now I have a scheduled job which make some servers inaccessible for a few minutes and when they run everyday at 9PM, and every day I receive critical notifications.

Is there a way to set a time which a specific trigger for a host will not run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of deactivating the trigger configure a [maintenance window](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/maintenance) for that time so you will not receive notifications.